# How to download file with save as dialog using mvc or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

In my project i have given option to download file. All files are present in folder on server. I have done this using anchor tag

```
<a class="nav-link" href="/images/myfile.jpg" download >Download</a>
```

It downloads the file in downloads folder by default but i want **save as dialog** to ask the location where to download/save file.

In C# i have tried this. The following code also download file in downloads folder

```
public ActionResult index()
{
  Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
  Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=121.jpg");
  Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/images/121.jpg"));
  Response.End();

 return View();
}
```

Comment: Simply use `return File(Server.MapPath("~/images/121.jpg"), "image/jpeg")` instead of view page and try setting `Content-Disposition` header to `attachment`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply return the file directly instead using `return View()` by using `return File()`:

```
public ActionResult index()
{
    string path = Server.MapPath("~/images/121.jpg");
    string contentType = "image/jpeg";

    return File(path, contentType, "121.jpg");
}
```

Take note that **save dialog window is dependent on client's browser settings**, you can't control it from server-side. If the client browser enables automatic downloading to specified folder, then the file will downloaded into given folder name.